# how to play audio chunks of single mp3 file without interruption in android?

Tags: java, android

can anybody tell me how to play audio chunks of single mp3 file without interruption?

Comment: Are you saying you want to take sections of an mp3 file (five seconds from the beginning, then the middle, then the end, say) and then play them all in a row?

Comment: no,actually i have encrypted mp3 files.if i decrypt the whole file it takes approx 5 sec to play in galaxy tab,but in lower configuration device it is too slow.so i want to make some chunks and play them if there isnt any interruption.

Comment: Can you have two players, queue the second chunk in player 2 while player 1 is playing the first, swap to player 2 when player 1 ends, and then queue the next chunk in player 1 while player 2 is playing?  Then you wouldn't have to wait for each bit to buffer, because it would have been buffering while the other was playing.